# How should I handle the potential for collisions in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

You and I both want to go to a concert but there is only one ticket left. We both attempt to reserve that ticket at the same moment. A PHP script using the AWS SDK for PHP runs the following updateItem API call which attempts to change the "state" of the "ticket" from 0 (available) to 1 (on hold).

```
        try {
        $response = $ddb->updateItem(array(
            "TableName" => "tickets",
            "Key" => array(
                "tn" => array("N" => $request["tn"])
            ),
            "AttributeUpdates" => array(

                // set ticket state (ts) = 1...

                "ts" => array(
                    "Value" => array("N" => 1)
                ),
                <snip - more fields updated here to "own" the ticket>
            ),
            "Expected" => array(
                "ts"   => array(

                    // ...where ticket state (ts) = 0

                    "ComparisonOperator" => "EQ",
                    "AttributeValueList" => array(
                        array( "N" => "0")
                    )
                )
            ),
            "ReturnValues" => "ALL_NEW"
        ));

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->ErrorMessage(5, "Call to ReserveTicket failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Ideally DynamoDB would process these sequentially and the first one of us to make it through the network will win, flip the state to 1 and "own" the ticket, and the second request fails because the "Expected" state of 0 will not exist.

I am accessing if DynamoDB is +OK to use for this type of use case or if I need to stick to my good 'ol relational database. This code works, but I don't feel I can adequately test this. My questions:

1. Is this the right approach for this use case?
2. Has anyone seen any DynamoDB documentation that talks about the order requests are processed?
3. If this **is** a correct implementation, any suggestions for a testing regimen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB uses an optimistic concurrency control pattern to deal with your use case.  It is implemented as "Conditional Update". 
When using a conditional update, the API will write the item only if an attribute's value has not been changed since the read.
If it was changed, an error is raised and it is up to the application to take a decision.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate
for details.

Comment: But for that to work the requests MUST be sequential, right? This doesn't allow for the potentiality of simultaneous writes. That's where I am hung up. If updateItem requests arrive at the very same time then the state of the ticket in my example is 0 for both requests.

Comment: Without table locking, I don't see how you can 100% solve this use case.

Comment: No. This mechanism is designed to work in multi threaded environment. Conditional write operations are performed on DynamoDB side and is atomic. "Note that conditional writes are idempotent. This means that you can send the same conditional write request multiple times, but it will have no further effect on the item after the first time DynamoDB performs the specified update."

Comment: This isn't super testing for sure, but using family members on 5 different devices I was able to successfully conduct an experiment.  5 calls were made to reserve the ticket (above PHP code) in the exact same second on the server (unix epoch second) . Only one request won, the other 4 lost as is desired. So clearly it does seem to work as advertised. I'd like to see more requests in the same second (20 would be good). Maybe a CURL test of some sort and just flood the server for 2 seconds.